# Scraping a very specific section of a website?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a list of URL's (mesa$fullerurl) for documents and I am trying to scrape a specific section of text on each website (the paragraphs on Risk Factors). The problem is that there is no unique HTML tag that I can see for this section. The best way I can think of is to tell R to grab the text from the Risk Factors heading up to the next heading and then put that in a new data frame, k10, but I am not sure how to specify this in R. Thanks!
Here is an example of the document that I am trying to scrape from:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/72903/000007290319000010/xcel1231201810-k.htm

```
sec<-read_html("https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar? 
action=getcompany&CIK=0000072903&type=10- 
k&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40")
xcel<- sec %>%
  html_nodes("#documentsbutton") %>%
  html_attr("href")
xcel<-data.frame(xcel)
xcel$xcell<-paste0("https://www.sec.gov",xcel$xcell)
xcel$fullurl<-paste0(xcel$xcell,xcel$xcel)
as.character(xcel$fullurl)

mesa<-map_dfr(xcel$fullurl, ~ .x %>% read_html() %>%  html_table() %>% . 
[[1]])
mesa<-subset(mesa,mesa$Type=="10-K"|mesa$Type=="10-K/A"|mesa$Type=="10- 
K405")
mesa
s<-gsub("(.*)/.*","\\1",xcel$fullurl)
table(xcel$fullurl)
xcel$fullurl<-s
xcel$fullurl<-paste0(xcel$fullurl,"/") 
mesa$fullerurl<-paste0(xcel$fullurl,mesa$Document)
as.character(mesa$fullerurl)
mesa$Document[mesa$Document == ""] <- NA
mesa$fullerurl 
#Below is the problematic part 
k10<-map_dfr(mesa$fullerurl, ~ .x %>% read_html("") %>%  html_nodes("") 
%>% html_text(""))
```